# Orbits of the conjugation action of $GL_3 (\mathbb{R})$ on the nonsingular symmetric $3\times3$-matrices

Tags: matrices, group-actions, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

Let $S$ be the space of all symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrices of full rank and with real entries. $GL_3 (\mathbb{R})$ acts on this space by conjugation, 
\begin{align*}
g.A = (g^{-1})^T A g^{-1}, \quad g \in GL_3 (\mathbb{R}), \quad A \in S.
\end{align*}
I have read (in the book in the references, p. 165) that if $\det A > 0$ (**EDIT:** And if $A$ is indefinite), then the orbit of $A$ contains the matrix 
\begin{align*}
\sigma_0 = \left( \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix} \right),
\end{align*}
but for some reason I am stuck trying to prove this.

**My attempt:**
If $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then $Q^T \hspace{-0.1cm} A Q = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)$ for some $Q \in O(3)$. Given that $\det A > 0$, either all of the eigenvalues are positive, or exactly two of them are negative. So if 
\begin{align*}
B = \left( \begin{matrix}
\text{sign } \lambda_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \text{sign } \lambda_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \text{sign } \lambda_3
\end{matrix} \right),
\end{align*}
we can write $C^T Q^T \cdot A \cdot Q C = B$ where $C$ is the diagonal matrix whose entries are $1/|\lambda_i|$ for $i = 1,2,3$. From this point, I hoped to be able to apply some permutation matrices to conjugate $B$ to an anti-diagonal matrix and then finally conjugate by some other matrix to ensure that the signs of this anti-diagonal matrix match those of $\sigma_0$.

Any ideas? Thank you.

**References:** *Ergodic Theory and Topological Dynamics of Group Actions on Homogeneous Spaces* by M. Bekka and M. Mayer

Comment: You are missing a hypothesis. If there is a nonzero real vector $v$ such that $v^T Av = 0,$ add in $\det A > 0,$ then you get the result.

Comment: Right, we want $A$ to be indefinite. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That certainly is false. The action in question is a [matrix congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence). By [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), the inertia of a matrix is an invariant under congruence. This means every matrix in the orbit containing $\sigma_0$ must have the same inertia as $\sigma_0$, i.e. it must have one positive eigenvalues and two negative eigenvalues. Clearly, this is not always the case if you only require that $\det(A)>0$, because $A$ may have three positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right. As Will Jagy also pointed out, the claim in the book also relies on $A$ being indefinite. I just edited the question to emphasize this.